# RVM error while running make install. Error comes while installing power_assert gem

Tags: ruby, rvm

Im trying to install ruby 2.2.2 in my arch machine. When I run rvm install, I get the following error. Tried several times. Even removed rvm and re-installed. Still the same issue.

```
○  rvm install 2.2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: arch/libc-2.21/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for arch.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.2 - #downloading ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.6M  100 12.6M    0     0   323k      0  0:00:40  0:00:40 --:--:--  340k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.2.2 - #extracting ruby-2.2.2 to /home/pubudu/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2 - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #installing - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of /home/pubudu/.rvm/log/1429407987_ruby-2.2.2/install.log
                          rake 10.4.2
                          rdoc 4.2.0
installing bundle gems:       /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
                          test-unit-3.0.8.gem
                          minitest-5.4.3.gem
                          power_assert-0.2.2.gem
./tool/rbinstall.rb:728:in `chmod': Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - / (Errno::EPERM)
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:728:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
uncommon.mk:253: recipe for target 'do-install-nodoc' failed
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Same issue. This worked for me:

```
rvm get master
rvm reinstall 2.2.2
```

I used the head version of rvm before...

Comment: Master and Head appears to be the same. In my case I switched from Latest to Master and it helped.

Comment: Did not work for me, had the same error after doing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
export warnflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
export optflags="-w"
rvm install "ruby-2.6.3" --with-out-ext=fiddle
```

Same issue resolved by above commands

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).