# Error in installing ruby-1.9.3-p551 on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I have a new OS 10.10.5 installed on my Mac which has a default ruby-2.0.0p481. However, I need ruby-1.9.3-p551 for specific reasons of our system. When I am trying to install ruby-1.9.3-p551 using RVM 1.26.11, I am getting the following error.
[Error for rvm install 1.9.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj38p.png)

I also tried running "rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang", but that too gave me an error as under.
[Error for rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjK5E.png)

I tried for searching ruby-1.9.3-p551.tar.bz2 binary file on mirror binaries and at other places but even that did not worked for me. Any help or pointers will be great.

Thank You :)

I tried "rvm get master" and the output is as under.

```
aparmar-mbpr:~ aparmar$ rvm get master
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
No GPG software exists to validate rvm-installer, skipping.
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/aparmar/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/aparmar/.mkshrc /Users/aparmar/.profile /Users/aparmar/.bashrc /Users/aparmar/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/aparmar/.profile /Users/aparmar/.bash_profile /Users/aparmar/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/aparmar/.rvm/ is complete.

# Ashish.Parmar,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

RVM reloaded!
aparmar-mbpr:~
```

After this I did rvm reinstall 1.9.3 and I got the same previous error

```
aparmar-mbpr:~ aparmar$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p551..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/aparmar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p551 to /Users/aparmar/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551....
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /Users/aparmar/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /Users/aparmar/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/CVE-2015-1855-p484.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #configuring...............................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #compiling...........................................................................................................................................|
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/aparmar/.rvm/log/1448483473_ruby-1.9.3-p551/make.log
     ossl_str_adjust(str, p);
     ^
ruby_missing.h:32:14: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'len'
  RSTRING(str)->len = (length);  \
              ^
ossl.h:137:5: note: in expansion of macro 'rb_str_set_len'
     rb_str_set_len((str), newlen);\
     ^
ossl_asn1.c:1336:5: note: in expansion of macro 'ossl_str_adjust'
     ossl_str_adjust(str, p);
     ^
make[2]: *** [ossl_asn1.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
aparmar-mbpr:~ aparmar$
```

I also tried rvm get head, but after that in the installation of 1.9.3 again I get the same above error

Comment: Please post text, not links to images.

Comment: Did you try to update? These two links has thi solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832732/error-running-rvm-make-install and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724941/rvm-error-while-running-make-install-error-comes-while-installing-power-assert

Comment: Hi Migore, I tried both these things, I have edited my original post, but I get the same error again.

Comment: I have also done "source /Users/aparmar/.rvm/scripts/rvm" but no success.