# rvm install error: Error running '__rvm_make install'

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm getting the following error when installing rvm with stable ruby or simply rvm and then any version of ruby. I've considered all previous questions/answers (like updating rvm with "rvm get head", "rvm get master" uninstalling and reinstalling rvm etc.) but I still get this error.

```
ruby-2.2.2 - #extracting ruby-2.2.2 to /home/ajp/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2....
ruby-2.2.2 - #applying patch
/home/ajp/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.2/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.2 - #applying patch /home/ajp/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.2/openssl3.patch.
ruby-2.2.2 -
#configuring.........................................................
ruby-2.2.2 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.2.2 -
#compiling................................................................................
ruby-2.2.2 - #installing..................
Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of /home/ajp/.rvm/log/1482739246_ruby-2.2.2/install.log
from /home/ajp/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/request_set.rb:249:in `each'
from /home/ajp/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/request_set.rb:249:in `install_into'
from /home/ajp/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/request_set.rb:141:in `install'
from /home/ajp/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:394:in `install'
from /home/ajp/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/lib/rubygems.rb:558:in `install'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:722:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
uncommon.mk:253: recipe for target 'do-install-nodoc' failed
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724941/rvm-error-while-running-make-install-error-comes-while-installing-power-assert